# How to find the meta-data for provider with authority com.google.firebase.fileProvider?

Tags: android, firebase, android-manifest

> This is LogLines

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't find meta-data for provider with authority com.google.firebase.fileProvider
   at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:606)
   at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:579)
   at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:417)
```

> This is what I did in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <provider
      android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"       
     android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

> How i can resolve this crash error?

Comment: My title is my question and I showed the error message from logcat, and the following code is what i did in my Code. My ask is Is this right way to resolve this error or any other modification should to be done inside provider tag because inside provider there is no refrence to FirebaseProvider.

Comment: Thanks. You could put the provider_paths.xml in a different block as it is confusing now. It does not belong to manifest as you state.

Comment: `com.google.firebase.fileProvider` You should post the code that causes the exception. And certainly because it does not match: `${applicationId}.provider`.